# Run task after first compete

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

How I can run third method after playing will finish ?
Playing audio in other stream

I have some method

```
- (void)play {
    [self runTask:^{
        [self someMethod];
    } withCompletion:^{
        [self secondMethod];
    }]
;}


- (void)someMethod {
    NSLog(@"method 1");
    [[SoundManager sharedManager] playSound:@"" complete:^{
        [self thirdMethod];
    }];
}

- (void)secondMethod {
    NSLog(@"method 2");
}

- (void)thirdMethod {
    NSLog(@"method 3");
}


- (void)runTask:(void (^)())task withCompletion:(void (^)())completion {
    if (task) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            if (task) {
                task();
            }

            if (completion) {
                completion();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Maybe you can me show how I can get the end of audio and then run some method?
I use AudioPlayerDelegate Method

```
- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag {
```

Comment: take a look to `dispatch_group_async` and `dispatch_group_notify`

Comment: If i'm not mistaken your block will leak. You've created a strong reference cycle.

Comment: "If i'm not mistaken your block will leak. You've created a strong reference cycle" - How i can do it ?